# How can i disable selectable tedit for cut/copy in firemonkey android platform?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I use Delphi 10.2 Tokyo version. Also i use Firemonkey Android Platform.

How can i disable selectable tedit for cut/copy in firemonkey android platform?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

answer is simple: you can not! at least not with Tedit. But you could take a look of native android Edit for this (look Alcinoe implementation TALEdit)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.